# Do Team Attacks and Counter Attacks count toward weapon skill?

Tags: disgaea

As per the title, when your character counterattacks, or is part of a Team Attack, do they gain skill in their weapon?

If it makes a difference, I am playing the PC version currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Gamefaqs Q&A](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ds/945236-disgaea-ds/answers/98627-question-about-weapon-skill-levels-), counterattacks do add to the weapon skill.

> Weapon Skill is gained by every attack of the weapon,including skill like skull spliter,don't need to finish the enemy.
>
> The only exeption is staff;it gains weapon skill by Attacks and Magics.